# ath9k_htc wifi must be unplugged and plugged back in after each boot

Tags: wifi, drivers, arm, usb-device, yocto

Context, I have an stm32mp135d odyssey board running my own linux image made with yocto and booting from an SD Card. I have a cheap ath9k wifi USB dongle plugged into it and have a nuisance issue where the wifi interface will not show up until I unplug the dongle and plug it back in.

After a reboot here are some outputs to help you guys troubleshoot.

Kernel info in case it matters.

```
root@stm32mp1:~# uname -a
Linux stm32mp1 5.15.67 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 15 01:01:46 UTC 2024 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

lsusb output.

```
root@stm32mp1:~# lsusb -v

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 040d:3801 VIA Technologies, Inc. VIA USB2.0 WLAN
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x040d VIA Technologies, Inc.
  idProduct          0x3801
  bcdDevice            1.08
  iManufacturer          16 VIA TECH
  iProduct               32 VIA USB2.0 WLAN
  iSerial                48 12345
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x003c
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           6
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

the interface not showing up

```
root@stm32mp1:~# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: end0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:ce:65:8a:8d:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: end1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:7b:ce:1d:79:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:9d:05:79:2b:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And the output of dmesg showing that there is a failure to load the ath9k firmware

```
root@stm32mp1:~# dmesg | grep -i "ath9k"
[    0.351901] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[    4.369966] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[    4.387041] usb 2-1: Direct firmware load for ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw failed with error -2
[    4.401769] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
[    4.421233] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Failed to get firmware htc_9271.fw
[    4.427899] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
```

**AFTER** I unplug and plug the module back in I get the following in dmesg

```
[  467.033794] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[  467.334719] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[  467.585338] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[  467.854226] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[  467.858250] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[  468.025043] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlu1: renamed from wlan0
```

And the interface appears

```
5: wlu1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:12:7b:21:6f:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

At this point I'm also able to use hostapd and wpa_supplicant on the interface without any issues at all. It just requires that manual reset at the beginning. Given that this is an embedded device I don't want to have to do that in my final product. Based on the dmesg output it looks like it may be trying to load the ath9k firmware too early in the boot process and fails, so I either need a way to delay or just reset it automatically after linux boots. I feel a vague notion that maybe I could do something with a udev rule to accomplish this? But I'm not sure.

Things I have tried

1. resetting the USB device programmatically as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line)
2. `modprobe ath9k`
3. `modprobe ath9k_htc`

Answer (score 0):

Self answering this.

My solution is to reset the USB device after the boot is complete, the method that worked for me is shown in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line) post.

The user there does this

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.6/authorized"
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.6/authorized"
```

where the /sys path to the wifi device to reset can be found with this script (or any other method)

```
for X in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*; do 
    echo "$X"
    cat "$X/idVendor" 2>/dev/null 
    cat "$X/idProduct" 2>/dev/null
    echo
done
```

There may be more elegant solutions, but for my purposes this works.